# add multiple array to corresponding comboboxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

I have several arrays named : Array1, Array2, Array3, ... and also some comboboxes named: cboArray1, cboArray2, cboArray3, ....

How can i write a GENERAL code to add elements of each array to corresponding combox. I know following code works, but its not GENERAL and ABSTRACT.

```
For i = 0 To Array1.Length - 1
            cboArray1.Items.Add(Array1(i))
Next
For i = 0 To Array2.Length - 1
            cboArray2.Items.Add(Array2(i))
 Next
...
```

Working procedure maybe as follows: 1. Find all comboboxes in form (easy) 2. extract name of a combox (easy) 3. find similar-named array from code (difficult) 4. ....
I can use other sets like List, ... if it makes sense.

Comment: It is not GENERAL and ABSTRACT because you are adding SPECIFIC data to a SPECIFIC combobox.  Its easier to use the datasource: `cboArray1.DataSource = array1`  You could also write a method which takes a CBO and an array (or list) and tediously copies each element to the items collection

Comment: Thanks. in both ways i must repeat a similar code for every pair of array-combobox. By General, i meant a way to avoid this repeat. In future, i may add arrays and comboboxes and i'm looking for a way to avoid writing new code.

Comment: Read the last part - create a method and pass the CBo and array.  The DataSource approach prevent having to copy the data to the control.  One line of code.

Comment: I think i understand what you say. Let's suppose -after a while- i've added 100th array to my code. Now beside defining that array, I should go and add another code like this: cboArray100.dataSource= Array100 . I want to omit the above code for every new defined array. Of course, it such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're asking for using Reflection...though I'm not sure how useful this really is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Array1 As String() = {"cat", "dog", "fish"}
    Private Array2 As String() = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma"}

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WireComboBoxes(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WireComboBoxes(ByVal container As Control)
        For Each ctl As Control In container.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox AndAlso ctl.Name.ToUpper.StartsWith("CBO") Then
                Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox)
                Dim arrName As String = cb.Name.Substring(3)
                Dim fi As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = Me.GetType.GetField(arrName, Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
                If Not IsNothing(fi) Then
                    cb.DataSource = fi.GetValue(Me)
                End If
            ElseIf ctl.HasChildren Then
                WireComboBoxes(ctl)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks man. It works as i expected. Also, i learned a new concept: 'Reflection'